# Multiple IP addresses in Safari

Tags: safari, proxy, network

Is it possible to choose which IP address will be used to browse the web? I am connected to a VPN which created tun interface with different IP addres so now I have two of them.

I would also like to browse the web through the second one, the tun interface.

Comment: Yeah, I found the answer.. If you're using VPN via OSX Network settings, [there is a setting](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mac.tutsplus.com/authors/jordan-merrick/vpn-send-traffic.png) under Advanced button to "Send all traffic over VPN connection". If you're using OpenVPN with Tunnelblick, the same "Route all traffic hrough the VPN" is under Settings->Advanced->While connected.

Comment: If you found the answer, you should write it as an answer and accept it instead of only commenting (you can write an answer to your own question).

Comment: If I have under 10 reputation, I have to wait 8 hours..

Comment: You're right, didn't see that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I found the answer.. If you're using VPN via OSX Network settings, [there is a setting](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mac.tutsplus.com/authors/jordan-merrick/vpn-send-traffic.png) under Advanced button to "Send all traffic over VPN connection". If you're using OpenVPN with Tunnelblick, the same "Route all traffic hrough the VPN" is under **Settings->Advanced->While connected**.